# How to optimize DynamoDB Query response time?

Tags: database, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-dynamodb

We're using API gateway + Lambda function + DynamoDB to fetch data and using the DynamoDB query method. For 260.4KB data ( Total item count:675 | Scanned Count: 3327 ) it's taking 3.49s.

**Requirement**:

We've 4+ clients, we are calculating client sales user's data on daily basis and storing it in the DB.

Table Structure:

- **Primary Key**: ClientId
- **Sort Key**: Date+UserId
- **Other Attributes:** Date

In Query - We are using Primary Key ClientId & Date to get the data.

Currently, we're using on-demand mode for the DynamoDB yet we feel the response time > 1s is too much.

Is there any way we can improve this using any AWS configurations?

**Update[24/03/2021]**
In Lambda - We are using NodeJs.

```
module.exports.executeQuery = async(dynamoDbClient, queryInput) => {
  return await new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    dynamoDbClient.query(queryInput, (err, users) => {
      if (err) {
        reject(handleQueryError(err));
      }
      else {
        resolve({
          statusCode: 200,
          users,
        });
      }
    });
  });
};
```

Memory Provisioned to Lambda = 128 MB

Comment: That seems long, can you add a sample item to your question and a screenshot of the query latency metrics? Which language are you using and how much RAM have you provisioned to Lambda? If you're using Python in Lambda you might benefit from [this blog post](https://aws-blog.de/2021/03/complexity-costs-read-performance-for-nested-dynamodb-items-with-different-lambda-configurations.html) about performance measurements with DynamoDB and different configurations I literally just published (disclaimer: I wrote this, it's on topic).

Comment: you can use https://github.com/alexcasalboni/aws-lambda-power-tuning to help you detect the best power configuration to minimize cost and/or maximize performance. I highly recommended it and I have used it myself in similar scenarios (but instead of DynamoDB it was RDS Proxy)

Comment: If you are only using lambda for querying purpose and not doing any changes to data returned from dynamo, you can try using api gateway as proxy for dynamodb.

https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/using-amazon-api-gateway-as-a-proxy-for-dynamodb/

Comment: I think that you are not using the right tool. Even if you can use DynamoDB to get what you need, it doesn't mean that you should use it. DDB is best for a lookup of one or a few records not query over many records.

Comment: @Maurice, Currently we are storing all client's data in a single table that has data > 6k, now we are planning to segregate the data based on the client and store it in a separate client table. updated the question too.

Comment: Increase the memory your Lambda function has and check if it gets faster, from my experience there is a **very** significant difference.

Comment: @Maurice, thanks after increasing the Lambda memory it's fast. Also, we segregated the clients in different tables now.

Comment: @GuruDeepak Cool, I've added my suggestion as an answer :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As suggested in the comments, I'd start by increasing the memory size of the Lambda function.

**Lambda CPU performance scales with memory and from my experience parsing larger responses from DynamoDB benefits a lot from more CPU performance.**

I did a performance analysis [in a blog](https://aws-blog.de/2021/03/complexity-costs-read-performance-for-nested-dynamodb-items-with-different-lambda-configurations.html) (disclaimer: my employers techblog, it's on topic - albeit for python) a couple of days ago and found significant differences between the performance for different memory sizes.

Answer (score 4):

You're getting 3327 results so the ~3.5s response time doesn't surprise me. Sounds about right from my experience.

The underlying problem here is a lack of threads or parallel processing. You can easily prove that is the case, run this CLI command:

```
aws dynamodb scan --table-name YOURTABLENAME --total-segments X --segment 0 --select COUNT
```

Replace `YOURTABLENAME` and `X` where X should be the number of of MBs of data in your table. So if you have 100MB of data, use 100.

This will do a parallel scan with X threads. It will return in about 1s and its getting every item in your table.

You can then try a scan with `--total-segments 1` (which runs with one thread) and see how much longer it takes.

What this demonstrates is the needs to get large amounts of data in parallel threads.

Your partitions are too large. If you try a key with less data, perhaps 10's of records I expect the query is fast.

You might want to look into [sharding techniques](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/bp-partition-key-sharding.html) to reduce the amount of data in your partitions, then you can Query those partitions in parallel. Note that DynamoDB does not provide a BatchQuery method, which is a shame, so you have to write your own parallel Query methods.